# How to run an executable file from a different directory without cd or modifying the PATH?

Tags: command-line, bash, executable, paths

Variations similar to what I want to ask exist but I could not find the exact question, so I'll ask it here.

Let's say I have a comiled `.c` file resulting in the executable `ex` which is located as `/mnt/f/C_F/ex`. I can very well execute it from within `/mnt/f/C_F` by `./ex` but what if I want to do that from `/mnt/f` say (or any directory for that matter). I don't want to add `/mnt/f/C_F/` to PATH for this.

I could not find a solution and I suppose it's not possible to do so. Please confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an absolute path to that file.

`/mnt/f/C_F/ex`

This should always work regardless of your current working directory.  Generally, you probably should prefer absolute paths within scripts for this reason (though there are important exceptions).

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the relative or full path to your executable

When you're in `/mnt/f`, you can run:

```bsh
C_F/ex
# or
/mnt/f/C_F/ex
```

Comment: For some reason, using only the absolute path works for me. I had been trying the `C_F/ex` and it didn't work, which is why I asked this. Nevertheless, I have a way now. Thanks.

Comment: @MadhurPanwar `C_F/ex` should work if you are in the directory that contains `C_F`--that is, if you are in the `/mnt/f` directory. Paths that start with a `/` are absolute paths and they work from anywhere. Paths that do not start with `/` (but start with a directory name) are relative paths; they are resolved relative to the current directory.

Comment: @EliahKagan I understand the differences between relative and absolute paths. Even I expect `C_F/ex` to work when I am inside of `/mnt/f`. But it doesn't work. I don't know why. Could it have something to do with the fact that I am using 'Ubuntu subsystem for Windows' and not vanilla Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: @MadhurPanwar I'm not sure why that's not working. You may want to post a new question about that specifically (since this question doesn't seem to cover it, and since you seem to consider this question to be solved, having accepted [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186670/22949)). If you do, I recommend including the output of `file C_F/ex` and `ls -l C_F/ex`, running both from `/mnt/f`. This should give some relevant information including whether the problem is specific to attempting to *run* the file.

Comment: @EliahKagan It was my mistake. Actually the `.c` whose resulting executable is `ex` contains `exec` which executes another executable present only inside `C_F`. I had been overlooking it the whole time. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

**Any [path](http://foldoc.org/pathname)<sup>1</sup> to the executable file that contains at least one `/` works.** The presence of a `/` character in a command name tells the shell that you are asking it to run a specific file and that you are specifying the specific place where that file is to be found. This is part of the syntax the shell expects; in most other contexts it is acceptable for (relative) paths to contain no `/` character.

For an executable that is not in the current directory, *that's any path to it at all*. There is no way to write the path of a file in another directory without using at least one `/`. This makes running files in other directories the simpler case, even though it is less familiar.

- [Absolute paths](http://foldoc.org/absolute%20path)--like [`/mnt/f/C_F/ex`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186670/22949)--start with `/`.
- [Relative paths](http://foldoc.org/relative%20path) to a file in another directory--[`C_F/ex`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186669/22949) when you are in the `/mnt/f` directory--always contain a `/`, even though it is not at the beginning. A relative path without a `/` is just a filename, identifying a file in the current directory. (The converse is not true though. A relative path may contain a `/` yet still refer to a file in the current directory; see below.)

  Note that relative paths must still actually refer to the file you want if they are to work, and whether or not a relative path refers to the file you want [depends on what directory you are currently in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186667/how-to-run-an-executable-file-from-a-different-directory-without-cd-or-modifying#comment1983197_1186669), since the are resolved relative to the current directory.

For an executable that *is* in the current directory, the shortest relative path does not generally work, because it does not contain a `/`. Thus, this is the more complicated case, even though it is more familiar. When you are in the directory where an executable `ex` is located, you can't just run `ex`, even though `ex` is a perfectly good relative path to that executable.

The reason it does not work is that a command name that does not contain a `/` is not treated as a relative path or any path. Instead, [it is treated as a filename and searched for](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) in the directories listed in `$PATH`.<sup>2</sup>

**This is why you use `./ex` when you're in the same directory as `ex`.** Every directory contains a `.` entry that refers to the directory itself. This [provides a way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261392/11938) to write a relative path that identifies the same file as `ex` but has a `/` in it and is thus usable as a command name that the shell treats as a path.

A `./` prefix is thus not a special syntax, but simply the second-simplest way to write a relative path to a file in the current directory, and the simplest way to do so of those that contain a `/`.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> In this answer, I use "path" to mean "pathname." This is the most common use of "path," but not the only one. "Path," as I use the term here, should not be confused with the *executable search path*, which is the collection of directories whose paths are listed, separated by `:` characters, [in the `$PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#Unix_and_Unix-like).</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Command names that do not contain a `/` may also be resolved as non-external commands, such as shell builtins and shell functions.</sub>

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thanks. I did not know earlier that why in current directory I needed to do the `./`, but now I do.